# using pycharm + gevent greenlet.join() no longer blocks

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, gevent, greenlets

so after the upgrade of gevent to 1.1rc4 (from 1.0.2) while running through pycharm, I can't get greenlets to join properly... take this code for example:

```
from gevent import monkey, Greenlet, hub
import gevent

hub.Hub.resolver_class = ['gevent.resolver_ares.Resolver']
monkey.patch_all()

def sleepy(time):
    gevent.sleep(time)
    print "done like a good script"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = gevent.spawn(sleepy,10)
    g.start()
    g.join()
    print "if this is the only log line, then join didn't work"
```

will output:

```
 "if this is the only log line, then join didn't work"
```

from the IDE, it executes normally using the same interpreter from the CLI

I have followed the code in the cli and gui and there is a difference in behavior `greenlet.join()` caused by a change in behavior in `hub.switch()` :

```
 def switch(self):
    switch_out = getattr(getcurrent(), 'switch_out', None)
    if switch_out is not None:
        switch_out()
    return greenlet.switch(self)
```

where that last line, will return immediately, before the greenlet is executed...
the pycharm debugger wont let me step into that code...

any help would be great... coroutine flow control is hard enough when it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a bug at jetbrains, it was marked as a duplicate of: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14992

I haven't looked at all of my debug issues with gevent, but this simple case was fixed with the 2016.1 release that went out 3/23/2016

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm does some magic (not always nicely) with stdin.

Try to flush your stdin right after each print statements by doing this:

```
import sys
sys.stdin.flush()
```

Also add `time.sleep(1)` at the very end.

It might be that your script exit before the print statement was outputed. I don't know if that will work, but definitely worse a try.

If it does not work, try outputting to a file and see if that works properly.

Comment: actually pycharm's release yesterday fixed this issue.